# How to see lombok source code in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, lombok

I have the Lombok plugin setup in NetBeans IDE and my code builds fine. I can see the Lombok generated methods in the structure view. What I want is some way to actually see the source Lombok generates for each of the methods. I realize I can delombok the file, but I'm wondering if there is some way I can flip a switch to show or hide the Lombok generated code (How to delombok in NetBeans?).

Procedure to see the source code of Lombok methods.

Comment: Someone could write a plugin for that, but no one has. tbh probably because when you're familiar with what it's doing, that feature doesn't sound useful to me. Delombok is the best you've got.

Comment: Personal opinion: netbeans is a technological cul de sac. Hardly anyone is investing time in developing plugins for it in 2022. If you want nice plugin support for 3rd party tools, you'll be way better off in the long run by switching to IntelliJ. It doesn't have this specific feature, but I'd bet my house that the Lombok support is better in general.